# how do I change my counter's speed on tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to make a money counter with a input box that changes the speed of the counter to display the inputed amount of money per hour, however it's very choppy and doesn't seem to work with different numbers. any advice?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
money = 0
money_per_hour = 1000
root.minsize(500,300)

def monies():

    global money_per_hour
    box = spinbox.get()
    box = int(box)
    final = 3600/box
    final = round(final)
    final = final * 1000
    money_per_hour = final
    countup()


button = tk.Button(text = "show me the money", fg = "green", command = monies)
button.pack(side = "bottom")

spinbox = tk.Spinbox(from_=0, to=1000000, width=5)
spinbox.pack(side = "bottom")

label = tk.Label(root, text = "$" + str(money), foreground = "green", font = ('calibri', 40, 'bold'))
label.pack()


def countup():

    global money
    money += 1
    label['text'] = "$" + str(money)
    root.after(money_per_hour, countup)

root.after(money_per_hour, countup)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you print out `money_per_hour`? It may be very large.  Also you should cancel running `after()` in `monies()`.

Comment: how do I cancel after()?

Comment: `after()` will return an id and you can use `.after_cancel(id)` to cancel the scheduled `after()`.